# Error - 200: parsererror on send of mail using phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've just started using phpmailer to send mail instead of the basic mail function.
I've added the phpmailer function to an ajax script to send a mail on a certain event. The script works perfectly fine on its own, but as soon as I add the `$mail->send();` command, I get an error:

```
"Error - 200: parsererror"
```

It does work - the mail gets sent, but it doesn't return correctly to the calling procedure.
I've cut down my code a bit to remove extra validations and functions that aren't relevant to this particular issue.
The calling code is:

```
    jQuery('#save-supplier').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      
    $('#save-supplier').html('<i class="fa fa-cloud"></i> Saving...');
                                  
    var formData = new FormData($('#edit-supplier-form')[0]);
      
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./ajax/ajaxSendphpMail.php",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData:false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $(location).attr("href", "supplier.php?supplier_code=<?php echo $supplier_code; ?>");
        },
        error: function(data){
            var errorMessage = data.status + ': ' + data.statusText;
            alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
            $('#save-supplier').html('<i class="fa fa-save mr-5"></i> Save Changes');
        }
    });
  
    return false;
});
```

});

And the script with the phpmailer command is:

```
    ob_start();
session_start();
require '../inc/_global/db_con.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require '/var/www/vhosts/compleit.com/vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = 'compleit.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = 'smtp@compleit.com';
    $mail->Password   = 'cAp$xxxYY';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->Port       = 587;

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('myemail@mydomain.com');
    $mail->addAddress('gavinb@compleit.com');
    $mail->addReplyTo('donotreply@mydomain.com');

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'test email';
    $mail->Body    = 'email body';
    $mail->AltBody = 'email body';

    $mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // no exception reporting - no need to know if email succeeded or failed
}
```

Previously, I was sending mail through the standard mail command and I had no problem.
But now that I’ve switched to phpmailer and I get the 200 parsererror.  The only way to stop that is to comment out the `$mail->send()` command.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of obvious problems here. PHPMailer does almost nothing until you actually call `send()`, which is why you're only seeing stuff happening then.

Your JS is expecting valid JSON in responses, but you have `SMTPDebug` enabled, which will produce lots of output that's definitely not valid JSON, so set that to `0` or `false`. This is what's causing your parser error, and it will be visible in your browser's dev tools if you look at the XHR requests it logs.

You're also missing a content-type header in your response, so your script (if it's obeying the rules) will not parse the response. Add a line **before** you produce any JSON output:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

In the case of a successful send, you're not `echo`ing anything.

In debug situations like this, **debug the individual components first**. Make sure your PHP code is working (both success and failure paths) *before* you try to use it from JS. At the moment you're trying to debug your PHP code from JS, which is unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Keep in mind that i've been left high and dry by my developers and am trying to do what I can while I wait for them.  I didn't write this code - the script was parsing the response OK.  
I just took the phpmailer example 'script' and inserted it into my code and changed as appropriate.  
Yes, I know that the phpmailer does nothing until I call send() - that part at least is obvious. :)
I had tried setting SMTPDebug to 0 but that didn't help unfortunately.  I tried 'false' today but no luck either.

Comment: I see that the 'header' line should be there but that's not the cause of this problem (IMHO).  I know this because if you take the previously working code and simply add the $mail commands with no return statements, you get this error.  And then if you comment out the 
$mail->send() statement, it works again.

Comment: So check what’s coming out of the script at the server end. Don’t debug PHP from the client.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a noob.  But I'll try to work out how to do that.

Comment: The topic has been edited with all field validation and all returns removed, as I suspect that the original code may have led readers to focus on data encoding and validation and not the basic issue of the parser error that occurs with the $mail->send() command.  In the code above, the js script expects no json responses, yet I still get the error and simply by commenting out the $mail->send(); command, it is 'fixed' (but with no mail).